Complex Spectrogram Interpretation
Given chirp signal like this:

Performing complex spectrogram function, returning real part and imaginary part:
signal # 1D vector
sr # integer scalar
real_part, imaginary_part = compute_spectrogram(signal, sr)

Computing magnitude and angle based on real_part and imaginary_part.
magnitude = square_root(real_part^2 + imaginary_part^2)
angle = arctan(imaginary_part/real_part)

Encoded to HSL where h=angle, s=1, and l=magnitude`, returning spectrogram like this:

I know the interpretation of magnitude which basically white pixel represent bigger while black represent nothingness.
For the color, this is interesting, I have no idea what that hue or angle part represent.
But it seems that it only tell us the cyan which basically 180 degree and red which basically 0/360 degree represent the oppositness.
Now, if I expect the spectrogram is outputting yellow constant color over the time instead of cyan. What the original signal data looks like without modifying any spectrogram encoding function.

The blue and red hue along the bottom is the phase of the DC portion of your signal (just as you see hues for other frequencies during the modulation, given the frequency is the position along the vertical axis).
This is consistent with your DC (constant levels) being completely real: for that the phase can only be 0° or 180°. Apparently the spectrogram processing is inverting that as when the DC value is positive it is reporting 180°, and when it is negative it is reporting 0° (I would expect it to be the other way around).
Regardless, if you want it to report yellow, where it is now blue, multiply it by the following complex signal to rotate -135° (or $0.75\pi$):
rotator = np.exp(-1j * 0.75 * np.pi * np.arange(len(signal))
signal_rotated = signal * rotator

